# List organization by file name in R

Tags: r, list, char

I'm trying to create a list of data separated by month and year (40 years worth).  The data currently has the name structure (Year)-(Numeric Month)-(Var).nc. I'd like to get all the data into its appropriate list created below.  Not exactly sure how to proceed from here.  Any guidance is appreciated.

```
files_nc <- list.files(pattern = ".nc")

year <- vector("list", length = 40) 
month <- vector("list", length = 12)

names(year) <- c(1978:2017)
names(month) <- c("Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul", 
   "Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec")  

for (i in 1:40) { 
   year[[i]] <- month
}
```

Comment: Could you please show the output you want? It's not clear

Comment: I'd like to iterate through the files and place each of them in the correct list.  So id like something like year$1987$March <- 1987-03-T2.nc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're asking for, but I believe this should work.  I'm assuming you're loading in a list of files, and each file is associated with a year and month.

```
file_names <- list(names(files_nc))

file_names_split <- lapply(file_names,function(x)strsplit(x,"-"))

for(i in 1:length(file_names_split)) {

  y <- which(names(year) == file_names_split[[i]][[1]][1])
  m <- as.numeric(file_names_split[[i]][[1]][2])

  year[[y]][m] <- files_nc[[i]]

}
```

In general, this method should work.  If it works I'd take the time to rewrite the for loop as an apply statement.

Comment: Yeah, question was vague, but you got it.  The strsplit function was the missing piece I needed.  Thank you!  I'll look into how to transform for loops into apply statements as I've heard thats the way to go for most loops.